# Delete json object based on the date inside the value: Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that holds various dates as values, I need to delete all objects in the json on the condition that they include these dates.

Below is my JSON file, it has been cut for example's sake (as it goes up to the 60's & there can be multiple objects inside each of the lists). So when targeting the file it needs to be collectively, rather than stating "0" or "1" / [0] or [1] etc:

```
  {
    "transactions": {
        "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "Western Asset Inflation-Linked Opportunities &amp; Inc",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Full)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000",
                "party": "Democrat"
            },
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2021",
                "asset_description": "Goldman Sachs Access Treasury 0-1 Year ETF",
                "asset_type": "Other Securities",
                "type": "Purchase",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000",
                "party": "Democrat"
            }
          ],
        "1":[
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2019",
                "asset_description": "Western Asset Inflation-Linked Opportunities &amp; Inc",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Full)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000",
                "party": "Democrat"
            }
          ]
    }
  }
```

My code attempts to collect all objects on the condition that their values include the year of the date and then delete them from the JSON file:

```
import json

data = json.load(open("xxxtester.json"))

delete_keys = []

for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2013':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2014':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2015':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2016':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2017':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2018':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2019':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2020':
        delete_keys.append(value)
for value in data['transactions']:
    if data['transactions'][value] == '2021':
        delete_keys.append(value)


for key in delete_keys:
    del data['transactions'][key]


open("xxxtester.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Is there a way for me to include code that can select a value if it INCLUDES x inside the value? As opposed to if the ENTIRE value is x. eg. calling the value by "2021" if the date is "11/29/2021", as there are multiple different dates so the easiest thing for me to do is call them by their year and delete them. I only need 2022 dates and newer.

Below is my desired output:

```
  {
    "transactions": {
        "0": [
            {
                "transaction_date": "11/29/2022",
                "asset_description": "Western Asset Inflation-Linked Opportunities &amp; Inc",
                "asset_type": "Stock",
                "type": "Sale (Full)",
                "amount": "$1,001 - $15,000",
                "party": "Democrat"
            }
          ],
    }
  }
```